# How can we create azure-disk based persistent volume claim and use them from a POD in Kubernetes?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am unable to find an example where the secret regarding Azure storage account can be passed during POD creation or PVC creation. An example will really help.I followed the examples [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/azure_disk/claim), but it didn't work.

Comment: Any more questions? And if it solves your problem please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create pvc:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: azure-managed-disk
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: managed-premium
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

if you are using a really old AKS\or not AKS, you'd also need to create storage class:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: managed-premium
parameters:
  cachingmode: ReadOnly
  kind: Managed
  storageaccounttype: Premium_LRS
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-disk
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

use pvc:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: nginx:1.15.5
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 128Mi
      limits:
        cpu: 250m
        memory: 256Mi
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/mnt/azure"
      name: volume
  volumes: // this is where you reference the pvc
  - name: volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: azure-managed-disk
```

Comment: Don't I need to provide some access credentials? Using azure-file for storage class needs some secrets and that actually is working.  I am not using AKS, but reather setting up the K8S cluster myself.

Comment: no, you dont need secrets for that, you need to configure `cloud-provider-azure` properly: https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-azure/blob/master/docs/cloud-provider-config.md. ah it appears from 1.15.0 you can use secrets to configure it: https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-azure/blob/master/docs/cloud-provider-config.md#setting-azure-cloud-provider-from-kubernetes-secrets

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

To use the Azure Disk as the persistent volumes, there are two forms, one is the dynamic disk and another is the static disk. You can follow the steps in [Dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disks-dynamic-pv) and [Static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disk-volume) to create persistent volumes based on the Azure Disk as you need.